# Unable to restore docker MYSQL database in Jenkins

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to run the following command in Jenkinsfile

```
sh "docker exec -i ${d.id} sh -c \\\'exec mysql -uroot -p\\\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\\\"\\\' < \$(pwd)/mydb.sql"
```

what I get from the build console output is

```
+ docker exec -i b432d812cfcd026dd4e95cbc6df3f995d3a8f6fbd54c84d83fc5cea0f4a2c213 sh -c 'exec mysql -uroot -p"MakePasswdGreatAgain"'
```

and I got the following error

`mysql: 1: mysql: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

where do I go wrong? why the line after `<` is terminated?

Comment: `sh "docker exec -i ${d.id} sh -c \\\'exec mysql -uroot -p\\\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\\\"\\\' < \$(pwd)/mydb.sql";` putting `;` may resolve this termination.

Comment: Tried it. it does not work

Comment: The line is terminated since you have the `\\\'` before the `<`, if you want `<` to be part of the command sent to the second `sh` try `sh "docker exec -i ${d.id} sh -c \\\'exec mysql -uroot -p\\\"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD\\\" < \$(pwd)/mydb.sql\\\'"`